# How to represent this proposition with set notation and how to prove it

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry

Considering this axiomatic:

Axiom I1: For all line exists at least two points intersected by it and **one** that is not intersected by it.

Axiom I2: For all pair of points exists one unique line that intersect they.

Definition 1: We say that the points A, B, C ..., are collinear if exists a line that intersect all they.

I have this proposition:

For all line pair, or it are intersected on unique point or are not intersected.

My try was this, considering the universe as the set of points on plane:

$$ \forall{(l,m)}\exists{A}[(l \cap m = \emptyset) \oplus  (l \cap m = {A}) ]$$

And to proof this, I think trie negate this logic formula, getting:

$$ \exists(l,m)\forall{A}[\neg((l \cap m = \emptyset) \oplus (l \cap m = \{A\}))] $$

But I got stuck, (1) I don't know if this transformation for set notation is correct. In case that is correct, (2) how to negate the $\oplus$ operator and (3) how to negate $l \cap m = \{A\}$

> PS: sorry my english, I am not fluent.

Comment: A few things for starters: Don't jump straight into notation. Understand what the universe in which you are working in is. How are you defining lines? Points? Intersections? After that's resolved, then we can start to think about the problem.

Comment: Yep, let me put the the two axioms and the definition that I have.

Comment: This is not the kind of argument you need formal notation for. I suggest you think the logical geometric argument through in words in your native language. Write your argument so that a human being can follow it. Then translate into English if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use two sorts of variables; one for *lines*: $l,m,\ldots$, and one for *points*: $A,B,\ldots$, with the assumption that lines are sets of points. Thus, $A \in l$ means that point $A$ lies on line $l$.

The theorem to be proved is: $\forall l, m [(l \cap m = \emptyset) \lor \exists ! A (A \in l \cap m)]$, assuming that $l \ne m$.

Having said that, the condition is equivalent to:

> $(l \cap m \neq \emptyset) \to \exists ! A (A \in l \cap m)$.

So, assume that we have $A, B$ with $A \ne B$ such that $A,B \in l$ and $A, B \in m$.

By Ax.2 there is a *unique* $l$ such that $A, B \in l$, that means: $l=m$.

Comment: So, just to has certain that I understand, when $l \cap m = \emptyset$ always we fall in case that $A \in \emptyset$ that it always is false, right?

Comment: @pic - Yes; lines are sets of points. To say that the intersection of two liens is empty means that there is no common point.